# checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: gcc, g++

I got this error while compiling gcc 4.3.3 from source and I can't find a way to solve this issue. I'm using Ubuntu 64 bit. I also tried to compile simple source files with gcc and g++ and they are working.

```
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Here is the [link for logs](https://pastebin.com/BMuV580R)

Anyone any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: 4.3.3's `configure` is too old. It tries to use obsolete compiler flags like `-V` that modern gcc no longer recognises. Try `gcc -V` and see.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes but do you have any suggestion in order to fix it?

Comment: Install an older OS in a VM and an older compiler from packages on that OS and use that co compile your version.